# YouTube Data API V3: Unable to get channel uploads using playlistItems.list() method

Tags: javascript, while-loop, async-await, youtube-data-api

My function works for the first call only; meaning I only get 50 video IDs and then it throw a lot of errors (400 error). And then when I use the nextPageToken, it doesn’t work. I believe it’s because I’m calling the API inside a while loop, and I end up with an infinite loop.

Here's my current code:

```
const DEFAULT_CHANNEL_UPLOADS_ID = "UUJQJAI7IjbLcpsjWdSzYz0Q";
async function getPlaylistItemsById(
  id = DEFAULT_CHANNEL_UPLOADS_ID,
  nextPageToken = undefined
) {
  const YOUTUBE_CHANNEL_UPLOADS = [];
  try {
    const request = await gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list({
      part: ["snippet, contentDetails"],
      maxResults: 50,
      playlistId: id,
      nextToken: nextPageToken,
    });
    const response = await request.result;

    for (const item of response.items) {
      YOUTUBE_CHANNEL_UPLOADS.push(item.contentDetails.videoId);
    }

    nextPageToken = response?.nextPageToken;
    if(nextPageToken === undefined) return;

    while (nextPageToken !== undefined) {
      getPlaylistItemsById(DEFAULT_CHANNEL_UPLOADS_ID, nextPageToken);
    }

    return YOUTUBE_CHANNEL_UPLOADS;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a few mistakes in my previous implementation, and luckily I managed to fix them.

Here's what I fixed:

- I used `pageToken` instead of `nextToken`.
- I moved `YOUTUBE_CHANNEL_UPLOADS` array to the global scope.
- Used an `if statement` to return in case `nextPageToken` is equal to `undefined`.
- Otherwise, call the function recursively and pass the `id` alongside `nextPageToken`.

```js
const DEFAULT_CHANNEL_UPLOADS_ID = "UUJQJAI7IjbLcpsjWdSzYz0Q";
const YOUTUBE_CHANNEL_UPLOADS = [];
async function getPlaylistItemsById(
  id = DEFAULT_CHANNEL_UPLOADS_ID,
  nextPageToken = undefined
) {
  try {
    const request = await gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list({
      part: ["snippet, contentDetails"],
      maxResults: 50,
      playlistId: id,
      pageToken: nextPageToken,
    });

    const response = await request.result;

    for (const item of response.items) {
      YOUTUBE_CHANNEL_UPLOADS.push(item.contentDetails.videoId);
    }
    nextPageToken = response.nextPageToken;

    if (nextPageToken === undefined) return YOUTUBE_CHANNEL_UPLOADS;

    return await getPlaylistItemsById(id, nextPageToken);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```